error after upgrading from angular 12 to angular 15
i'm upgrading an angular project from angular 12 to 15.
after doing all the necessary steps, i still get this error after building:

knowing that i already removed all the ~ from the css imports and the import the error is referring to in my styles.scss is like so:
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";

what i'm i missing?

Did you remove tilda (~) from your import?

@IslombekHasanov i did and it still gives the same error, also i cleaned the npm cache.

Please do not upload images of text; [edit] this question to include it as text.

Try to write node_modules/ instead of ~.

tried that to did not work.
